# AWS codepipeline stage approval using API gateway and lambda not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sns, aws-codepipeline

we have a AWS code-pipeline for Angular Application build and deployment.

I have added a approval stage where user needs give approval using the link provided in mail.

following is pipeline work flow

- when pipeline reached approval stage, it will send out a mail to a SNS topic, mail body will contain  links for Approve and Reject. these are API gateway url to pass the pipeline details and user approval to integrated lambda.
  example of API url: https://xxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v0/pipeline-approval?action=Approved&pipeline=pipeline-name-here=release-approval&pipelineexecutionid=xxxxxxx

And the mail I'm receiving containing symantec link as it's coming from AWS, https://clicktime.symantec.com/34RBC48WLEQRUG7Vc?u=https%3A%2F%xxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com%2Fv0%2Fpipeline-approval%3Faction%3DApproved%26pipeline%3Dpiplinexxx%3Drelease-approval%26pipelineexecutionid%3xxxxxx

- below is the lambda function code

```
import json
import logging
import re
import time
import boto3

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
MAX_WAIT_FOR_RESPONSE = 10
WAIT_INCREMENT = 1

def handler(event, context):
  logger.info('REQUEST RECEIVED:\n %s', event)
  logger.info('REQUEST RECEIVED:\n %s', context)
  pipeline = event["queryStringParameters"]['pipeline']
  stage = event["queryStringParameters"]['stage']
  action = event["queryStringParameters"]['action']
  approval_action = 'transition'
  pipelineexecutionid = event["queryStringParameters"]['pipelineexecutionid']
  client = boto3.client('codepipeline')
  r = client.get_pipeline_state(name=pipeline)['stageStates']
  print(r)
  s = next((x for x in r if x['stageName'] == stage and x['latestExecution']['pipelineExecutionId'] == pipelineexecutionid ), None)
  print(s)
  s1 = s['actionStates']
  print(s1)
  s2 = next((y for y in s1 if y['actionName'] == approval_action ), None)
  print(s2)
  t = s2['latestExecution']['token']
  print(t)
  client.put_approval_result(
      pipelineName=pipeline,
      stageName=stage,
      actionName=approval_action,
      result={
          'summary': 'Automatically approved by Lambda.',
          'status': action
      },
      token=t
  )
  logger.info("Status message: %s", client.put_approval_result)
  if action == 'Approved':
    return {"statusCode": 200, "body": json.dumps('Thank you for approving the release!!')}
  elif action == 'Rejected':
    return {"statusCode": 200, "body": json.dumps('rejected.')}
```

The issue is after reaching the approval stage it's sending out a mail but it's not waiting for user input, it's automatically getting Approved or Rejected itself with in 2 to 5sec.

please help me what is going wrong here, why Lambda not waiting for response from API and why it's Approving or rejecting automatically.